# Producer/consumer in Grails?

Tags: design-patterns, grails, queue, producer-consumer

I'm trying to implement a Consumer/Producer app in Grails, after several unsuccessful attempts at implementing concurrent threads.
Basically I want to store all the events coming from a clients (through separate AJAX calls) in a **single queue** and then process such a queue in a linear way as soon as new events are added.

This looks like a **Producer/Consumer problem**:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

How can I implement this in Grails (maybe with a timer or even better by generating an event 'process queue')?

Basically I'd like to a have a **singleton service** waiting for new events in the queue and processing them linearly (even if the queue is loaded by several concurrent processes).

Any hints?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than implement it all yourself, I would recommend using Java Messaging Service.  It handles exactly the type of problem you are talking about.  Further, Grails has a JMS plugin.

Sun Docs on JMS: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/index.html

Grails JMS Plugin: http://www.grails.org/JMS+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to implement the same sort of a system and went with [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for the messaging broker, and used the [RabbitMQ plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rabbitmq) for Grails to interface with it.

I chose RabbitMQ because it had the features I was looking for (scale, speed, reliability) and was built on the AMQP standard, meaning I could have my producers and consumers written in any language I needed without worrying.

Grails works very well as both a producer and a consumer and has the advantage of still being able to work with the full GORM domain of your application.

To scale, either the producer *or* consumer end of the queue, all I have to do is spin up more grails instances and adjust the consumer thread count, so it works really well.